# LaTeX3: l3keys Multiple-Choices Keys and Startup Value for Predefined Choice Integer Variable

Tags: latex3, expl3, l3keys

In the `interface3` documentation it can be read (what follows is not a literal quotation) that the variable `\l_keys_choice_int` is available to be used as an index register for a multiple-choices key with its values starting up from `0`. Nonetheless, according to my experience with the code below, it is as though the starting value is actually `1`.

This is my class, in a file insightfully called `myclass.cls`:

```
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e,xparse}
\ProvidesExplClass
    {myclass}
    {2013/08/25}
    {1.0}
    {myclass}

\bool_new:N  \g_myclass_enum_bool
\bool_new:N  \g_myclass_enumalt_bool

\NewDocumentCommand \SetTBool { m }
 {
    \bool_gset_true:c
     { g_myclass_\tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} _bool}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \TypeBool { m }
 { \bool_if:cTF { g_myclass_#1_bool } { T } { F } }

\keys_define:nn { myclass }
 {
   alter .choice_code:n =
    {   
       \AtBeginDocument{Option ~ Index: ~ \int_use:N \l_keys_choice_int\par}    
       \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_keys_choice_int } =  { 1 }
        { \SetTBool { enum } }
        { \SetTBool { enumalt } }
    },
   alter .generate_choices:n = { enum, enumalt }
 }

\ProcessKeysOptions { myclass }

\LoadClass{memoir}
```

Then I have a document file by the original name `mydoc.tex` reading thus:

```
\documentclass[alter = enum]{myclass}

\begin{document}
\TypeBool{enum}\par
\TypeBool{enumalt}
\end{document}
```

What I get in my typeset document is `1 T F`, whereas according to the documentation I should get `0 T F`. Moreover, if I set the class option `alter = enumalt`, I get `2 F T`. Am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you have on older copy of `interface3`: we changed generally from index-from-zero to index-from-one a little while ago now. Thus your observation is correct: the index for `\l_keys_choice_int` begins at one.

Comment: Oh, ok, the documentation I'm using is dated December 2012.

Comment: Btw, before posting another question that can be solved trivially... I'm having trouble with an ``expl3``-coded class of my own which is based on the ``memoir`` class when I try to load the ``xcolor`` package before ``memoir``. I don't run into trouble if I load ``xcolor`` after ``memoir``, though. Do you know something about this?

Comment: @Marcos I'd need to see an example, I'm afraid

Comment: Well, it's as simple as adding ``\RequirePackage{xcolor}`` after the class header in the code in this post. I get the message ``Command \@namelet already defined``. Maybe it is that ``xcolor`` defines a macro by that name, and ``memoir`` defines another macro by the same name.

Comment: @Marcos Not our fault: try just loading `xcolor` before `memoir`!

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't get your point. I'm not blaming anyone... Loading ``xcolor`` before the keys declaration would allow me to use its facilities in the keys' code. No worries, though.

Comment: @Marcos `\let\@namelet\relax` or `\let\@namelet\undefined` prior to loading the offending package/code and the test whether it's already defined shouldn't throw an error.